# Typescript compile separate ts files, webpack

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

I'm trying to use straight up npm as a build tool to compile typescript files for angularjs.

I have a typescript structure liek this.

```
    ts
        home
            Home.Controller.ts
            Home.Directive.ts
            home.html
            Home.Service.ts
```

I'm using a webpack.config.js file to compile the ts files.

```
    var glob = require("glob");

    module.exports = {
      entry: glob.sync('./src/app/**/*.ts'),
      //entry: './src/app/app.ts',
      output: {
          filename: './src/www/js/output.js'
      },
      resolve: {
          // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
          extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
      },
      module: {
          loaders: [
              // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
              { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
          ]
      }
    }
```

This outputs a single js file in `/src/www/js/output.js`

What I want is an output structure like this.

```
    js
        home
            Home.Controller.js
            Home.Directive.js
            home.html
            Home.Service.js
```

I can't update the webpack.config.js file everytime I add a new ts file so I need a way to copy the ts structrue to the js folder and compile the ts files.

Comment: Looks like you just want to use tsc then? webpack is for... packing :)

Comment: can you explain what tsc is?

Comment: the standalone typescript compiler